# How to open my project link in chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome

In my angular 5 application when user opens my project like "www.sample.com/sales" in other than chrome browser, I want to show a popup and opens the same link in chrome browser automatically. I'm able to find the browser type from "window" object but not able to open the same link in Chrome browser. Please suggest me some sample code or reference links

Here is my code

```
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
if(! isChrome) {
   // Open a pop up (modal)
   // Redirect / open the link in chrome
}
```

Comment: You can't access one browser from another in web page. What environment are you running this on?

Comment: this will not work if it runs on client side

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for reply,  we are using angular 5.